# what is User_Alias Host_Alias Runas_Alias Cmnd_Alias how to configure it

Tags: linux

Anyone please help me to solve my problem i am using Centos my kernel version is 2.6.32 i want to know what is User_Alias,Host_Alias,Runas_Alias,Cmnd_Alias in sudoers file. and how does it work how to configure it.

Comment: http://linux.die.net/man/5/sudoers

Comment: I appreciate your help but i am unable to configure sudoers file please give me any  examples i can see that and i can configure it. about User_list,Host_list,Cmnd_list,Runas_list

Comment: It explains what each of those is in the manpage. Here's an example for `User_list`: `A User_List is made up of one or more user names, user ids (prefixed with '#'), system group names and ids (prefixed with '%' and '%#' respectively), netgroups (prefixed with '+'), non-Unix group names and IDs (prefixed with '%:' and '%:#' respectively) and User_Aliases.`

Comment: In addition, http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/sudo/sudo-16/sudo/sample.sudoers has numerous examples.

Comment: Sorry for the  late answering thanks a lot for your kindness given me good examples